# How can I allow ONLY iMessage (and not web browsing) through a firewall?

Tags: security, messages, firewall

I've looked up what TCP ports iMessage uses to communicate with and Apple says:

> 80 (TCP)
>
> 443 (TCP)
>
> 5223 (TCP)

In my particular use-case, web browsing (80, 443) is not allowed.  But we would like to allow the use of iMessage.

Is this possible ?

I am hoping that *either* iMessage will work with only TCP 5223 enabled *or* there is an easily wildcarded apple DNS lookup that we could allow all three ports to and block all other http/https traffic.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply firewall away connections to servers that are not Apple's.

However, it does sound like a weird use-case that is probably in a grayzone of legalities.

Comment: I would assume that the owner of a router (or the internet link it connects to) is authorized to block whatever they want to block.

Comment: Yes, of course I could simply firewall away connections to servers that are not Apples - that is my entire question:  how to do this ?  Is there a well known IP range ?  Are all Apple IPs reverse-resolved to something.apple.com ?  Or the other way around ?  I am wondering if anyone has real-world experience accomplishing this and what it looked like ... and if the hostnames or IPs changed over time, etc.

Comment: Apple uses IP addresses starting with 17. If the address is 17.x.x.x then it is Apple.